# Create a C struct array in Go

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to call a C lib from a Go program using CGo. I have the following C files that makes up the C lib. But, I get the following error" cgo parameter has Go pointer to Go pointer". I am struck with creating a C struct array in Go.

```
caller.h

enum c_callerIdType{
    user,
    certificate
}

typedef struct _c_callerid
{
    c_callerIdType type,
    char* value
}c_callerId;

typedef struct _c_requiredprops{
    char* operationName,
    CallerId* caller_id_set,
    int caller_id_set_size
}c_requiredProps;

int log_caller_details(c_requiredProps);
```

```
caller.c

#include "caller.h"

int log_caller_details(c_requiredProps* rp){
    printf("Operation name is %s", rp->operationName);
    // printf the callerid details
    return 1;
}
```

I created a Go wrapper around this C library as follows.

```
main.go

package main

// #include "caller.h"
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"
import "fmt"

type CallerId struct{
    type string
    value string
}

type RequiredProperties struct{
    operationName string
    callerIds []CallerId
}

// a helper function to call in to the C lib
func callCFunc() int{
    var cRequiredProps C.c_requiredProps
    var requiredProps RequiredProperties
    var userCaller CallerId
    var certCaller CallerId

    // create user caller
    userCaller.type = "user"
    userCaller.value = "user1"

    // create certificate caller
    certCaller.type ="certificate"
    certCaller.value = "service1.widgetcorp.com"

    requiredProps.operationName = "UpdateWidget"
    requiredProps.callerIds = []{userCaller,certCaller}

    // convert from Go struct to C struct
    var cOpName = C.CString(requiredProps.operationName)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cOpName))
    cRequiredProps.operationName = cOpName

    var cCallerIds = make([]C.c_callerId, 2)

    for i,callerId := range requiredProps.callerIds{
        var cTempCallerId C.c_callerId
        cTempCallerId.type = C.c_callerIdType(callerId.type)
        var cValue = C.CString(callerId.value)
        cTempCallerId.value = cValue
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cValue))
        cCallerIds[i] = cTempCallerId
     }

    // this line throws error "CGo parameter has Go pointer to Go pointer" --> cRequiredProps.caller_id_set = (*C.c_requiredProps)  (unsafe.Pointer(&cCallerIds[0]))

    cRequiredProps.caller_id_set_size=2

    return 1
}

func main() int{
    fmt.PrintLn(callCFunc())
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I create an array of C structs inside Go and call a C function?

Comment: Please, format your code...

Comment: `CallerId` contains go strings, which internally contain go pointers. You need to use the correct C types from the start.

Comment: I feel myself dyslexic reading this code.

Comment: @LaevusDexter, sorry, I tried my best to format the code using indentation and proper variable names. This is my first post on SO and pardon my ignorance. Anything else I could do to make it more readable?

Comment: @JimB, thanks for the response. Is there any other alternative to changing the C struct? Any change would mean lot of work and breaking existing users. Could I extract the bytes from the Go string and pass it to the C struct? Is it possible?

Comment: @subsett: sorry, I missed some of the conversion you have from your Go types and the C types. I think you're attempting to do the right thing here, but missing a conversion. It looks like you're forgetting to create a C string for `callerId.type`. Depending onthe lifetime of the value, you may want to allocate `cCallerIds` with `malloc` as well, rather than with `make`

Comment: @subsett sorry, but your style is still hurt my eyes even with formating. Afaik, this error can't occur out of cgo call. You can check it yourself, line by line, here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/UhXen_B6gQG